# Is there a way For loading data on demand as user scroll through it in mudblazor select?

Tags: mudblazor

I have a mudblazor select which may have 100s or even 1000s of items. Is there a way to load it dynamically (i.e. by default load a small set at load and then as user scrolls or types something as a filter criteria in the drop down then refresh the content in the drop down as a response?

Thanks,
Hamideh